# Como salvar dados de um form automaticamente?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

Olá, boa noite, preciso de uma ajuda de vocês, quero salvar automaticamente o que for digitado em um text area no meu banco mysql, já ouvi falar que tem como fazer com Ajax, tentei com esse código que tenho ai, porém não está funcionando, os dados não estão sendo salvos.

```
    <script>
            setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.dpaulatreinamentos.com/system/teste03/views/pages/pegaIdLousa_edit.php?id_aula=<?php echo $id_aula; ?>',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            'Lousa': $('#editor5').val()
        },
        success: function() {
        } 
    });

}, 5000 /* 1000 = 1 segundo, aí o tempo você quem determina */);
        </script>
```

Parte do Form

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.dpaulatreinamentos.com/system/teste03/controllers/edit_lousas.php?id_aula=<?php echo $id_aula; ?>">
                <textarea name="Lousa" id="editor5" rows="20" cols="10">
            <?php echo $select_lousa; ?>
        </textarea>
        <script>
            // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
            // instance, using default configuration.
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor5' );
        </script>

  <input type="submit" value=" Salvar " class="btn-save-medium" />
</form>
```

Comment: Não esta salvando ou não está nem enviando os dados pro servidor? Se os dados vão mas não salvam, coloque o código que faz a inserção no banco.

Comment: Se eu clicar no botão os dados salvam normalmente, mais se eu apenas digitar os dados não são enviados, só ficam na tela mesmo mais no banco nada acontece

Comment: alguem sabe como fazer?

Comment: Seria mais viável armazenar esses dados ao digitar no localStorage do navegador. Somente com o click é que seriam inseridos no banco de dados.

Comment: Ai já não resolve meu problema, é um sistema de lousa digital, onde terei a primeira instancia com o professor digitando e em tempo real sendo mandados para o servidor e ao mesmo tempo o aluno acessando a parte de visualização dessa lousa, o que realmente não pode é ter o clique entende

Comment: Já fiz os testes no meu servidor e vou ter um delay de 3 segundos até tudo acontecer, acho que o suficiente para que a aula aconteça, mais precisava dessa parte primeiro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rode o seguinte código

```
$(function(){
  editor5 = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor5' );
  setInterval(function(){ 
    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "link",
      data: {
        valor: CKEDITOR.instances.editor5.getData()
      }
    })
  }, 3000);
  editor5 = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor5' );
})
```

Comment: Não funcionou o código

Answer (score 0):

William não entendi completamente o que deseja, mas vou tentar lhe ajudar com o que sei, caso não seja bem isso me avisa que edito.

Eu costumo usar `$.get` em jQuery mesmo

```
$.get("local.php", //executa o arquivo no local especificado
   {"nome_variavel1":variavel1, "nome_variavel2":variavel2}, //variaveis a serem postadas
   function(data){ //função de retorno
      alert(data); //alerta com o retorno
});
```

Levando isso em consideração e lembrando que não é obrigatório se usar o form, você pode fazer requisições assíncronas(sem sincronismo) no php e sucessivamente no banco de dados.

Exemplo:

```
<textarea id="texto" ></textarea>
<button id="enviar"></button>
<p id="resultado"></p>

<script>
 var texto = $("#texto").val();
 if(texto != ""){ // se o textarea não estiver em branco
   $.get("local.php", // informe o arquivo aqui
      {"texto":texto}, //postando o texto para o arquivo
      function(data){ //solicitando a resposta do arquivo
        $("#resultado").html(data); //imprimindo a resposta no html
   });
 }else{ //caso o usuario o usuário não coloque nada
   $("#resultado").html("Escreva algo!!!");
 }
</script>
```

PHP(local.php)

```
include "conexao.php"; //inclua seu arquivo de conexão com o banco ou descreva sua conexão, suponhamos que o método de conexão se chama $conn

$texto = $_POST['texto'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO (texto) VALUES ('$texto')"; //aqui vai ser o insert no banco
if($conn->query($sql)==TRUE){ //realizando a execução da query utilizando o método de conexão com o banco $conn, se tudo correr bem imprimi "Sucesso"
  echo "Sucesso"; //isto retornara para $("#resultado") se tudo der certo
}else{ //se não gera uma mensagem de erro
  echo "Houve um erro na inserção de dados no banco!"; //isto retornara para $("#resultado") se tudo der errado
}
```

Na verdade é bem simples, conforme for treinando vai ver isso, só tem que cuidar para não se perder!

Comment: Então, o meu sistema é para ensino a distância ao vivo por video-conferencia, tem uma parte do meu sistema que se chama whiteboard, onde servirá como um quadro para os alunos e para o professor, no momento que se escreve no quadro já quero que envie para o php e já envie diretamente para o banco de dados sem ter que clicar em nada para que isso aconteça, ou seja, tem que acontecer de maneira automática de um em um segundo ou ao digitar no campo

Comment: A parte do aluno já resolvi, coloquei um echo com os dados do servidor e um refresh automático na página, já está funcionando, só a parte do professor mesmo que não estou conseguindo, que tem que enviar o texto automaticamente.

Comment: Desculpa a demora, espero que há tenha resolvido isso. Você pode usar o $('input').keyup(function(){ receba os dados aqui e mande para o php da mesma forma anterior }); assim sempre que o usuário digitar ele vai rodar o codigo, o ruim disso é que o código fica disparando varias vezes ao banco.